# How to parse and load tiles from .mbtiles?

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet, mapbox

I've been trying to parse and load tiles from a .mbtiles file using the  mbtiles-php script without much success. Followed the instructions on the repository site.

Installed a foo.mbtiles file on the same folder as .htaccess and tileserver.php. Also, this is how I have been loading the tiles:

```
var map = $(window).load(function() {
L.mapbox.map('map', './tiles/foo.mbtiles')
.setView([74.2343, -54.43534], 14);
});
```

Here's the [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVTXR.png)

Since L.mapbox.map does not parse .mbtiles, changed to L.tileLayer. Here's the new code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var map = L.map('map').setView([74.2343, -54.43534], 14);
L.tileLayer('./tiles/foo.mbtiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19
}).addTo(map);
});
```

I'm now getting several of these on my console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://43.000.00.0/tiles/foo.mbtiles/13/3888/3139.png
```

I had .htaccess usage disabled on my server. After enabling it, I'm now getting blank [tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN6So.png)

Comment: If you put the file in the same directory, why are you reading it from a subdirectory called `tiles`?

Comment: I suggest you include some more details about your setup; do not assume people are going to try to learn how this script works. Also elaborate on what "not working" means. What happens if you try to call `tiles/foo.mbtiles` directly from the browser?

Comment: @miken32 thank you for your comments. With "not working" I mean tiles do not load. The .htaccess and tileserver.php files are on that same subdirectory as the .mtiles file, but diferent from the index.html. Shouldn't it work either way? Anyway, I moved all the three files to the root directory and I am now getting the following: 'could not load TileJSON at http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/LisbonCF.mbtiles.json?access_token=pk.eyJ...' When I click on this link it opens a new window and gives me the following: {"message":"Tileset does not exist"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter for [`L.mapbox.map`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/l-mapbox-map/) accepts one of four things, a Mapbox.com Map ID, a comma-delimited list of Mapbox.com IDs, a TileJSON url or a TileJSON object. You are passing none of those, but a location to a MBTiles file.

If you're going to be serving tiles from a MBTiles file from a PHP server, you should be adding a [`l.tileLayer`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/l-tilelayer/) like `L.tileLayer('http://$MY_LOCAL_SERVER_LOCATION/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);`
This obviously depends on your local PHP configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. I updated the code accordingly (please check updated code on the top of the page), but I'm now getting several of these:  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://43.000.00.0/tiles/foo.mbtiles/13/3888/3139.png`   Any hint on why this could be happing?

Comment: I had .htaccess usage disabled, now getting blank tiles

Comment: Is there a log from the php script? Does the Mbtiles file contain data where your map currently is?

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work fine with *Leaflet*:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var map = L.map('map').setView([74.2343, -54.43534]);
L.tileLayer('./tiles/foo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 15
}).addTo(map);
});
```

PDO and GD must be enable on your server, as well as .htaccess